# Cron job not executing?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to execute a PHP script every two minutes on my server, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm using the following cron job:

```
2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /srv/www/<snip>/<snip>/run.php
```

I also tried:

```
2 * * * * php /srv/www/<snip>/<snip>/run.php
```

Both of which execute properly via the SSH command line.

I entered the cron job in with the following method via SSH:

```
crontab -e
```

I'm also running `Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS` if that matters.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote `2` in the minute column, so the job runs at 2 minutes past the hour, every hour. To run the job every 2 minutes, write

```
*/2 * * * * php /srv/www/<snip>/<snip>/run.php
```